# Batchprocess asking for CRS for every file

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, batch, jpg

I "wrote" a model using the graphical modeller which uses GDALs "translate" to convert one geotiff to one georeferenced jpeg. The model simply tells, which is the desired CRS and - most important - omits all otherwise manually necessary settings.
I then start the model as a batch process, since the conversion has to be done 350 times, loading all the to be converted files. For me it works fine.
For a colleague on the other hand, who would like to use this model, QGis asks for every file for a CRS.

Do you have any suggestions, why this could happen and how we could fix it?

Comment: From the menubar: `Settings > Options > CRS > CRS for new layers`, make sure the _Prompt for CRS_ option is **not** selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to mark this question as answered, I want to point anyone with the same problem to Joseph's comment.

> From the menubar: `Settings > Options > CRS > CRS for new layers`, make sure the *Prompt for CRS* option is **not** selected.